# An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'ABC_PrintCopyOriginal_TH' that is not defined in this report

Tags: reporting-services, report, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I'm getting the error:  "An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'ABC_PrintCopyOriginal_TH"' that is not defined in this report. when I try to view my reports in a web browser.  I'm executing this reports through a menu with button code.  When the page comes up I get the error.

I have added manually ABC_PrintCopyOriginal_TH in parameter level report design. this ABC_PrintCopyOriginal_TH was enum which I used to print filter expression based on menu item button. eg: when click on original menu button it needs to print original on report design if etc copy button wise versa....

Can you please help me how to resolve this?

Comment: Any hint on which report?
How is the parameter to be set if called from AX?

Comment: This is a custom report, and i have created parameter in report design manually and using filter expression like "=Switch(Parameters!ABC_PrintCopyOriginal_TH.Value = "Original", Labels!@ABC_Label:ABC_Original, Parameters!ABC_PrintCopyOriginal_TH.Value = "Copy", Labels!@ABC_Label:ABC_Copy)" when i tried to print report from original button that error occur.

Comment: Is it as simple as `ABC_PrintCopyOriginal_TH` vs `@ABC_PrintCopyOriginal_TH`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an SSRS Reporting server to host your reports? If so, have you deployed the report and tried restarting the Reporting server after the changes?

What editor are you using to edit the .rdl files?

If deploying and restarting the server doesn't help there is probably a typo in your .rdl file somewhere since you manually add stuff. Try using Report Builder and check if that gives you more info about the issue.

Comment: Yes SSRS, deployed and restarted after changes. XML editor. May I know why this error occur? where I missed?

Comment: @AbhilashAbhi With the information provided I cannot answer that question. I think you added the parameter in a wrong way. Try using the Report Builder like I said from Microsoft to see if the .rdl file is correctly setup.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53613

Comment: Here we have two custom report each report have there own copy and original buttons with each individual parameter filter expression like mentioned above previously.

Comment: But here those two custom reports are printed using print management setup formsetup but when i tried to make for one report as default in print management setup(customer invoice)formsetup. I got error "An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'ABC_PrintCopyOriginal_TH' that is not defined in this report". for one of custom report i'm able to print with original and copy by setting default in print management setup but where as other report when i tried setup and printing both custom menu item of button gave that error.

Comment: How do we achieve to print two individual custom reports for two custom menu items though print management setup by eliminating that error?

Comment: When I was try to open this designs through menu items instead parameter filter i suspect that public SRSCatalogItemName parmReportName(SRSCatalogItemName _reportName) method was overriding the previous custom public SRSCatalogItemName parmReportName(SRSCatalogItemName _reportName) method and printed that report design this stopping me. at least how we can achieve from this type of scenario? Why another class xyz_SalesInvoiceController_Extension is executing which in another model why my ABC_SalesInvoiceController_Extension is not executing?

Comment: Sir, stop putting all your questions as comments to my answer. Either try what I said which is basically: Debug the issue. Or create a new question since you're going into another direction completely.